# Simple unit testing with monoids

Tags: scala, unit-testing, specs2, monoids, scala-cats

Suppose I testing a function `echo: String => String`, which is just repeating the input, with `specs2`.

I can write a few tests like that:

```
class EchoSpec extends SpecificationWithJUnit {

  "echo should handle ASCII alphanumeric names" in {
    echo("abc") must beEqualTo("abc")
  }

  "echo should handle names with slashes" in {
     echo("a/b/c") must beEqualTo("a/b/c")
  }

  "echo should handle names with dots" in {
    echo("a.b.c") must beEqualTo("a.b.c")
  }

  "echo should handle non-ASCII names" in {
    echo("אבג") must beEqualTo("אבג")
  }
}
```

However I would prefer to get rid of the boilerplate code. So I am using `cats` monoids:

```
import cats.implicits._

def testEcho(expected: String): String => Option[String] = {str =>
  if (str == expected) none else s"$str != expected".some
} 

def testEchoes(expected: List[String]): Option[String] = 
  expected foldMap testEcho map (_.mkString(", "))

"echo should handle all names" {
   val expected = List("abc", "a/b/c", "a.b.c", "אבג")
   testEcho(expected) must beNone
}
```

Does it make sense ? How to improve/simplify it ?
Is the monoid is really necessary here ? Can I git rid of the boilerplate code from the above *without* monoid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List("abc", "a/b/c", "a.b.c", "אבג")
  .foreach(s => echo(s) must beEqualTo(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ScalaCheck

```
class EchoSpec extends SpecificationWithJUnit with ScalaCheck {
  "echo should handle all names" >> prop { s: String =>
    echo(s) must beEqualTo(s)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Good to know that `ScalaCheck` can be integrated with `specs2`. I would like to test `echo` with a constant given list of strings though

Comment: Still possible: `prop((s: String) => echo(s) must beEqualTo(s)).setGen(Gen.oneOf(strings:_*))`

Comment: Thanks again. Is it really better than just `strings foreach { s => echo(s) must beEqualTo(s) }` as suggested above ?

Comment: No, not necessarily if you just have a fixed list of strings.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for suggesting the property testing anyway.